# Matlab: Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make the code of someone else work. My main problem is, that i only have Matlab r2006b and he seems to have used a newer version. (for ex. i had to change some appearences of clearvars into clear). I now hav a problem in the following code snippet

```
function [ oData ] = sync( iData )
cType = {'text1' 'text2' 'text3' 'text4'};

for i = 1:4
    j = 1;
    while eval(['iData.' cType{i} '(j,6)']) > 30000
        j = j+1;
    end
    eval(['iData.' cType{i} ' = iData.' cType{i} '(j:end,:);']);
end
```

here i get the error

```
??? Error using ==> eval
Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error.

Error in ==> sync at 7
    while eval(['iData.' cType{i} '(j,6)']) > 30000
```

any suggestions?

edit:

> > iData.text1

ans =

```
 []
```

ans =

```
1.0e+010 *

    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    3.5801    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    3.5801    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    3.5801    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    3.5801    0.0000
.
.
.
   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    3.5801    0.0000

ans =

     []


ans =

     []


ans =

     []


ans =

     []
```

Comment: If matlab is not really necessary, try using [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (a OSS clone).

Comment: What is `size(iData)`? I assume the code has been written for it to be 1x1. The error indicates that it is greater than 1x1, if so the error will also occur on more recent versions.

Comment: 6x1 struct array with fields

Comment: I posted an answer converting it to handle non-scalar structures but the most recent edit suggests that the structure being non scalar is the error as only one of the `text1` fields contains anything. I suggest looking at how iData was created as it is likely the mistake is there instead

Answer (score 0):

One solution to make it work is to use `getfield`/`setfield` instead of `eval`, which I think is better anyway:

```
iData.text1 = rand(10);
iData.text2 = rand(10);
iData.text3 = rand(10);
iData.text4 = rand(10);

cType = {'text1' 'text2' 'text3' 'text4'};
for i = 1:4
    j = 1;
    while getfield(iData, cType{i})(j,6) > 30000
        j = j+1;
    end
    setfield(iData, cType{i},...
             getfield(iData, cType{i})(j:end,:));
end
```

But I did not try on your version of Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

As the structure is not scalar (1x1) you would have to add an additional loop to step through each scalar element of the structure.

also [dynamical field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) exits in Matlab the use of eval is unnecessary.

```
function [ oData ] = sync( iData )
cType = {'text1' 'text2' 'text3' 'text4'};

for kk=1:numel(iData)
    for ii = 1:4
        jj = 1;
        while iData(kk).(cType{ii})(jj,6) > 30000
            jj = jj+1;
        end
        iData(kk).(cType{ii})= iData(kk).(cType{ii})(jj:end,:);
    end
end

end
```